# This is somewhat related to data analysis. I am now learning about L1 data depth(aka spatial depth)

Tags: depth

[image: L1 data depth]

I have doubt in the L1 data depth formula stated below. What do " **Ep** " stands for in the given formula? Please help me....

Comment: This looks like a question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Are you sure *Ep* is not explained in the document you found this definition?

Comment: @kazemakase  It is not explained. I have searched a number of papers related to this for the explanation, but couldn't find it. Is it any general term?

Comment: I cannot help you because I'm not familar with the spatial depth metric. It is very unlikely that you will find help here at Stack Overflow where mostly programmers hang around. (The question has been viewed only 4 times in 19 hours.) Better ask at  [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) where you will find statistics experts that are much more likely to know the answer.